# Use sync function in await .then("sync") - javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, express, async-await

What will happen if i call a sync function in the`.then` part of an async `await .then`? I.e:

```
await asyncFunc(...)
        .then(res => sendMSG(res))
        .catch(err => next(err));

function sendMSG(res){ 
  xyz
}
```

`sendMSG` is a sync function called in the async part `.then`. What will happen if multiple asyncFunctions call sendMSG at once?

Comment: _"Will it work?"_ - What did your tests tell you?

Comment: Admittedly that wasnt well formulated, however the problem i have is still legit. What will happen, if multiple async calls want to use the sync function at the same time? Will it override eachother?

Comment: Even if it works, you are mixing the "traditional" `.then()` syntax and the newer syntactic sugar `async/await`, chich is clumsy. Ditch the `.then()` entirely.

Comment: What would be the equivalent in modern syntax then?

Comment: I told you exactly how to do that. Ditch the `.then()` entirely. Don't mix it with `async/await`, that's all. `const res = await asyncFunc(...); sendMSG(res);` Job done. You can even do `sendMSG(await asyncFunc(...));`

Comment: Alright thanks, that seems also seems to work. However i am still wondering if it may lead to errors if `sendMSG` will get called by multiple async instances at the same time.
I am sorry if that question may seem redundant, im new to async functions in javascript.

Comment: Yeah that's normal, asynchronism is one of the hardest concepts to grasp for JS beginners. Whether you get a problem by calling it multiple times concurrently depends on many things. Complexity and system speed mainly. You can use `await` sequentially, one after the other, in a `for` loop, so you avoid hammering the service you are calling.

Comment: Like I said, there is NO CONCURRENCY in javascript! Your function will never get concurrently run on multiple threads just by using the async keyword.

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen if i call a sync function in the.then part of an async await .then?

Then it will be called.

> at will happen if multiple asyncFunctions call sendMSG at once?

JavaScript operates on an event loop. Only one function will ever be running at a time.

An asynchronous function will be put on hold until whatever asynchronous business it is doing is done. Next time the event loop is free it will pick up the results of the asynchronous business and continue.

It will then block other asynchronous functions from picking up when *their* business is done until it is finished.

Comment: So if i understood you correctly, it wont be a problem that `sendMSG` is sync, as other async functions will be put on hold in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is fundamentally single thread. So there's no such thing as multithreading concurrency (some code being simultaneously executed on different threads).

Async (and Promises also) is just syntactic sugar for callbacks.

Comment: That's not exactly true any longer, since [Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) are available, which allow to spawn other threads

Comment: That is still a very limited form of multithreading as I see it. It seems more akin to posting to a webservice and expecting some results later than executing a function in your javascript code on multiple threads at once.